# Can't access developers apps

Tags: facebook, redirect, program-entry-point

I have created new facebook account, and have confirmed it with my phone numer using http://www.facebook.com/confirmphone.php

But unfortunately I cant access developers apps, every time I try to go there I am being redirected to my main facebook page.

Comment: What url do you use when attempting to access 'developers apps'?

Comment: Have you found a workaround? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you could use this URL:

https://developers.facebook.com/apps